# c++: Nested Lists: how to add an item to a list of Lists

Tags: c++, list, nested-lists

I am new on the board. I am using MS VS2008.
I am learning about list of lists. 
I am trying to add elements to a list which is part of a list of lists.

I have noted in my program where I am having a problem. 
When I debug it, "beth" is being added to the second list (division2), but when the loop is exited, "beth" isn't in the second list even though I have declared all my lists outside of the nested loop.

Any help would be greater appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
struct item
{
string name;
int age;
};
int main()
{
list<item> division1;
list<item> division2;

list< list<item> >WholeCompany;

item s; 
s.name="sandra"; s.age=43; division1.push_back(s);
s.name="Marc"; s.age=19; division2.push_back(s);
s.name="betty"; s.age=34;division2.push_back(s);

WholeCompany.push_back(division1);
WholeCompany.push_back(division2);

list< list<item> >::iterator WholCompIter;
list<item>::iterator itemIter;

for ( WholCompIter = WholeCompany.begin(); WholCompIter != WholeCompany.end();      WholCompIter++ )
    {
    //incorrect
    //list<item> listEntry = *WholCompIter;
    //instead use:
    list<item> listEntry = *WholCompIter;

    for ( itemIter = listEntry.begin(); itemIter != listEntry.end(); itemIter++ )
    {   
        //MY ISSUE IS RIGHT HERE! How can I add the value to the list, but      the list forgets it when it exit loop
        if(itemIter->name =="betty")
        {
            item s; s.name="beth"; s.age=65;
            listEntry.insert(itemIter,s);//problem is here.
                            //I have also tried
                            //listEntry.push_back(s) but the output doesn't show it

        }
    }
}
    //incorrect. 
//for(list<item>::iterator i=division2.begin(); i!=division2.end();++i)
//  cout<<i->name<<" "<<i->age<<endl;
    //instead use:
    for ( WholCompIter = WholeCompany.begin(); WholCompIter != WholeCompany.end(); WholCompIter++ )
{
    list<item>listEntry = *WholCompIter;

    for ( itemIter = listEntry.begin(); itemIter != listEntry.end(); itemIter++ )
    {   
    cout<<itemIter->name<<" "<<itemIter->age<<endl; 

    }
    cout<<endl; cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Besides the problems with the local list variable, also note that modifying a list while iterating over it may invalidate the iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just creating a *copy* here:

```
list<item> listEntry = *WholCompIter;
```

Instead, you need a reference:

```
list<item>& listEntry = *WholCompIter;
```

---

Also, you are printing from `division2` in the loop at the bottom. Remember that `WholeCompany` is only a copy of `division2` at the initialization. Since you've modified `WholeCompany` via the reference above, you need to access `WholeCompany` in the output loop at the bottom.

Comment: Hi Chris, I changed the code and I still get the same output. my list of lists WholeCompany doesn't seem to be changed. Any other suggestions? thanks.

Comment: @user1561949 What did you change the code to? Can you update your question to show your newest code? (Append the new code, don't overwrite the original.)

Answer (score 1):

Fix.

```
for ( WholCompIter = WholeCompany.begin(); WholCompIter != WholeCompany.end();      WholCompIter++ )
    {
    list<item>& listEntry = *WholCompIter;

    for ( itemIter = listEntry.begin(); itemIter != listEntry.end(); itemIter++ )
    {   
        //MY ISSUE IS RIGHT HERE! How can I add the value to the list, but      the list forgets it when it exit loop
        if(itemIter->name =="betty")
        {
            item s; s.name="beth"; s.age=65;
            listEntry.insert(itemIter,s);//problem is here.
                            //I have also tried
                            //listEntry.push_back(s) but the output doesn't show it

        }
    }
}
```

When you type `list<item> listEntry` you create local **variable** and then in your code assigns it to **copy** of returned value by `list<list<item>>::iterator::operator *` and when you change it, there is nothing effect on your `list WholeCompany`.

In strings

```
WholeCompany.push_back(division1);
WholeCompany.push_back(division2);
```

you push into `wholeCompany` **copies** of `division1` and `division2`, so, when you change contains of `WholeCompany`, contains of `division1` or `division2` **will not changed**.

Comment: Hi, I have added the list<item>& listEntry = *WholCompIter; to my code and I still get the same output: Marc 19, betty 34. I should get Marc 19, betty 34, beth 65. Any ideas why my code is still not working?

Comment: @user1561949 Yeah. You push in vector - copy of lists, where feel WholeCompany.

Comment: @user1561949 See my updated answer. You're printing the wrong list.